# Routes emeguity in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have defined the following route

```
          public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
 "portfolios", // Route name
 "{controller}/{name}", // URL with parameters
 defaults: new { controller = "portfolio", action = "portolio"} // Parameter defaults
```

);

and I want to show url as www.abc/portfolio/nameofportfolio

and the route is working and url is shown in correct pattern.

**problem**
But when I call

```
        www.abc/portfolio/create
```

It again route to above action instead of calling create action in controller.can some body tell me work around of this problem 
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please modify your code as follows :

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
        "portfolios", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        defaults: new { controller = "portfolio", action = "portolio",id = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
    }
```

The issue in your code is that you have not specified action in url parameters